# RPi pico W problem importing modules from subdirectory

Tags: pi-pico, modules, micropython

My directory structure on RPi:

```
/
firmware
   __init__.py
   functions.py
main.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty, in my main.py, I have:

```
import firmware

print(current_version)
```

while `functions.py` contains just:

```
current_version='1.0.0'
```

When I run, I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'current_version' isn't defined
```

My question is: how can I import functions from files inside the `/firmware` directory? I tried all Python ways known to me, including `sys.path.add` but to my great disappointment, it failed to work. Is Micropython on RPi Pico special in that way? According to [this link](https://wiki.micropython.org/gollum/Importing-Modules), it should work...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there, you just need to import the functions definition.

I have this structure

```
└── firmware
    ├── functions.py
    ├── __init.py__
```

`__init.py__` is empty.

`funtions.py` is

```
cat firmware/functions.py 
version="1.0.1"

def current_version():
    return version
```

Testing in Python

```
>>> from firmware import functions
>>> print(functions.version)
1.0.1
>>> print(functions.current_version())
1.0.1
```